# App security on rooted android phones

Tags: android

Can a app access and modify other app's files (like values/strings.xml) and stored data in a rooted android device? If my application is storing passwords, bank account numbers and other sensitive data in  internal storage, can another application running in a rooted device access this data and potentially alter the data? Would encrypting all the data on a password that user can enter before accessing the app help?

Comment: The only secure app is the one which hasn't been written.

Comment: My guess would be that a root is able to access other app's files. But I believe you can check if the phone is rooted, and then deny usage of the application if the phone is rooted.